# How to hash sha256 many times in python

Tags: python, hash, sha256, hashlib

I want to hash my password many times but it's hard to repeat codes many times depends on exponent.

So, for example in this code for exponent 2 and base 3:

> 3**2= 9

So I need to hash my password nine times!

I scanned all the web to find any code for help in Python but all found in C language.

Is there an easy way to hash my password many times in
Python with `hashlib.sha356` not `pbkdf2_hmac`?

Here is code for example:

> Hello World!

Result:

> c079473ced8ca65d5ce59cabf451ab7a513db97ab4d2266b9cb0c4d13383fb81

```
from hashlib import sha256

pw = input('Enter Password: ')
h1 = sha256(pw.encode('utf-8')).digest()
h2 = sha256(h1).digest()
h3 = sha256(h2).digest()
h4 = sha256(h3).digest()
h5 = sha256(h4).digest()
h6 = sha256(h5).digest()
h7 = sha256(h6).digest()
h8 = sha256(h7).digest()
h9 = sha256(h8).hexdigest()
print(h9)
```

Comment: did you try using a for loop ?

Comment: I'm curious: Why do this instead of `pbkdf2_hmac`?

Comment: @Ahmed Khattab I'm still newbie at python I don't know howto hash it for loop!

Comment: @Heap Overflow I guess that pbkdf2_hmac had different results of sha256, right?!

Comment: @tony I think so, yes. But does that matter?

Comment: @Heap Overflow there's different results if try openssl sha256 or pbkdf2_hmac so I'm trying to avoid forgetten also python sha256 results similar online tools that gave same results. try this one [https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html)

Answer (score 2):

```py
from hashlib import sha256

pw = input('Enter Password: ')
h = sha256(pw.encode('utf-8')).digest()

N = 10
for i in range(N):
    if i != N-1:
        h = sha256(h).digest()
    else:
        h = sha256(h).hexdigest()

print(h)
```